# How do i delete the whatsapp backup messages in windows phone permanently

Tags: whatsapp

How do i delete the whatsapp backup messages in windows phone permanently.I use a Lumia 720.
Also please advise how to disable whatsapp backup option in this phone.

Answer (score 3):

Edited:
Just watched over this [link](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/23607796), WhatsApp team made it pretty clear that you cannot delete your backed up messages on device. But there is a workaround.

- From application bar, go to >> settings >> chat settings >> backup
- Tap back up, a local copy will be saved in your phone storage.
- Uninstall and reinstall WhatsApp from the store.
- While you open the app after reinstalling you will be asked if you want to restore a chat history backup that was found. Simply choose not to restore your messages.
- Now backup again as mentioned earlier.

There you go, now you have a freshly installed clean slate state on WhatsApp. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question was related to Backup Messages in WhatsApp.

Comment: @vivek-parekh, sorry as i didn't notice the "backup" key word, just edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WP8 then you can't because you can't access the app files on memory.

But if you are using WP8.1 then you can use a file manager like [**Files**](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e) to delete the backups. Just follow these steps:

1. Open the file manager of your choice.
2. Go to the location where you installed WhatsApp, i.e. "sd card" or "phone".
3. Go to the folder "WhatsApp".
4. Go to the folder "backup".
5. Now you see the list of backups saved by WhatsApp and you can delete them.